# How to configure Google Places Autocomplete only to do requests if there are at least n letters in the input field?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, input, google-places-api

My Code:

```
var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
            document.getElementById('place'));              

var options = {               
        types: ['(regions)'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: "de"},
        offset: 3
    };  
function initialize() {             
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
       //some stuff here
    });
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Text from Google:

> Optional parameters
>
> offset — The position, in the input term, of the last character that >the service uses to match predictions. For example, if the input
>   is 'Google' and the offset is 3, the service will match on 'Goo'. The
>   string determined by the offset is matched against the first word in
>   the input term only. For example, if the input term is 'Google abc'
>   and the offset is 3, the service will attempt to match against 'Goo
>   abc'. If no offset is supplied, the service will use the whole term.
>   The offset should generally be set to the position of the text caret.

So why does the offset option not work? I'm getting suggestions after the first letter already. But I want to reduce the requests.

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem, please mark the answer as correct so that future readers will know that works

Answer (score 2):

You could use the jquery onchange event listener so for example:

```
$('#yourinput').on('change', function(e){
    var n = 3
    if($(this).value().length() < n){
        return
    }else{
        //do your autocomplete
    }
```

where `var n` is your number of characters you'd like to use as the start of geocoding.